# Is it better for SEO to use unique/playful (instead of generic) headings?

Tags: seo, content, heading

I have `h2` and `h5` headings with generic names, such as 'editor picks', 'tags', and 'all articles'.

Would it be better for SEO to give them unique and almost playful names with keywords?

Comment: thanks all. i think i have it sorted. thanks for the kind words Brian. i'll definitely follow your advice. Ciaran, i've changed it since.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend adding more descriptive keywords into your h1 and h2 lines such as:

- Service Shops in Location
- Following Service Trends
- Video: Description
- Video: Description A
- Video: Description B
- All Articles
- Service in Location
- Service Artist
- Network
- Popular Tags

Answer (score 1):

The outline of your current home page is as follows (Web Developer Toolbar > Information > View document outline):

```
<h1>Service in Location</h1>
<h2>Editor Picks</h2>
<h3>Video: Description of Video 1</h3>
<h3>Video: Description of Video 2
<h3>Video: Description of Video 3
<h2>All Articles</h2>
<h3>Related Article 1</h3>
<h3>Related Article 1</h3>
<h3>Related Article 1</h3>
<h3>Related Article 1</h3>
<h3>Related Article 1</h3>
<h4>Network Links</h4>
<h4>Popular Tags</h4>
```

It's reasonably well constructed and I wouldn't fiddle with it too much.

But, some thoughts:

- It won't hurt to add keywords to the H2s - something like 'Service Location, Articles' would be fine
- However, don't obscure the meaning of the sections with overly playful names
- Your site name 'Company Name | Location Service Phase' is **not** wrapped in a H1
- The H1 'Service in Location ' - could be considered cloaking.